# My generator won't start

Tags: generator

I've pulled all gas, pulled and cleaned carb. Reassembled and it starts with starting fluid, but continues to shut off. What else could be the problem?

Comment: If it starts with starting fluid, it must not be getting fuel.  Carbs can be a harder to clean that you might expect.  They have lots of very small passages and holes that can get clogged. See my answer to a related question [here](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/78676/43874).

Comment: Make sure you don't have a fuel shut off valve that is still turned off.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a common problem today since most gasoline has added ethanol.  The ethanol creates all kinds of problems for small engines, particularly ones that site for long periods of time between uses.  The ethanol tends to attack parts of the carb, and also absorbs water.  Further, the ethanol and water will separate out in the tank over time.  The water, being the most dense, settles at the bottom of the tank where it is pulled out first.  On top of that will be a layer of ethanol, since it is the next most dense. Finally, gasoline will be floating on top of all that.

Since you already flushed the bad gas, I think the carb is fubar and needs a rebuild.

Comment: I was worried about that too. Thanks for the advice

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "rebuild" but chances are good that the carb can be disassembled and cleaned well and work fine without having to buy any replacement parts.

Comment: Yeah, the ethanol gums them up. Try the tear down and thorough cleaning of the carburetor first. Before you spend a lot of money. Or take it to a small engine repair shop if you don't want to mess with it.